# Url route substring with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some routes;
`var url = '/traininggroup'` or `'/traininggroup/create'` etc.

How do I get just `'traininggroup'` with Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture it with this:

```
^\/([^\/]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bQ8vY1/1

If you use javascript, you can access it this way:

```
var url = "/traininggroup/create";
var reg = /^\/([^\/]+)/g;
var matches = reg.exec(url);
var match = matches[1];
console.log(match);  // traininggroup
```

Comment: my url is "/traininggroup/create" and url.match(/^\/([^\/]+)/gm) return to ["/traininggroup"]  where is wrong?

Comment: see my edit, it was general answer before, you haven't tag it as js question